# Amazon Cognito development using Mobile SDK

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am looking at Mobile backend service providers and trying some sample development. 
I have looked at feedhenry, parse etc. I came across Amazon Cognito as well. Looks, "AWS Cognito + Mobile SDK" supports MBaaS predominantly.

Could someone advise me to start trying MBaaS with AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 0):

A cognito dev guide can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html

Also here is a sample app: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample

You will likely want to integrate with API Gateway to create your backend APIs- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html

Comment: Thanks Mark.. Hence, AWS Cognito is MBaaS?